# How many ways are there to make a row of three books in which exactly one language is missing (order matters)?

Tags: combinatorics

Given 10 different English books, 6 diff. French books, and 4 diff. German books...

The way I went about this one I split into three cases. English missing, French missing, etc. 
Case #1: EGL misssin
Now there are two different subcases: more German books than French and vice versa. 
GER book > FRE books: (4*3)*6

FRE books > GER books: (6*5)*4

I go on for my other cases and subcases in the same logic and once I add them up I get a third of the answer. I was told somewhere in (4*3)*6 I had to multiply times 3 and so forth for my other subcases. However, I don't understand the logic behind this....thank you for your help

Comment: Another way of going about this that is quicker (doesn't involve so many cases/ subcases) is by first calculating the number of ways of ordering any 3 books, and then subtracting the number of ways of making a row with one book from each language. This second part is slightly harder, you have to use similar reasoning to joriki's answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In each of the cases, you have three different choices where to place the single book in the language of which there is only one book. (The order of the other two books also matters, but you've already accounted for that by counting e.g. $4\cdot3$ and not $\frac{4\cdot3}2$.)